# How to re-use simple static content across MVC views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Apologies if this has been posted before, however, I am struggling to distinguish the basic logic from the many more complex tutorials/samples that exist.

I have some basic **static** HTML that I'd like to re-use within multiple (but not all) Views:

```
<div class="logout">
    @Html.ActionLink("Log out", "Login", "Login", null, null)
</div>
```

How do I place this into a reusable component, and how do I then reference it in my Views?
All the other examples I've found today seem to pass Models to the object, or make it doing something dynamic, which is not required.

Comment: Do you know about partial views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your static html inside partial view and then include partial view in your view by
using `Html Helpers` such as `@Html.Partial()` or `@Html.RenderPartial()`.

Examples :-

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view"); }
@Html.Partial("Path/to/my/partial/view")
```

Comment: Stunning.  Thank you very much. I knew it would be simple!